# Do I have to specify that I want the password from results[0] if MySQL query returns 1 result?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

The used query returns only 1 row/result so when I'm trying to get the password column, do I have to write:

```
var hash = results[0].password;
```

I tried

```
var hash = results.password;
```

But then hash becomes undefined.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', [username], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var hash = results[0].password;
    console.log(hash);
  });

  res.redirect('/');

});
```

Comment: I guess since the application doesn't know it has only one row; yes. You have to still get the 1st ([0]) row from the results. If you'd , let's say, loop through everything; you wouldn't have to. Unless you implement a method that get's one row ".GetResultRow" for example, that could give back a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `results` is simply an array, even if there is one row, you still need to tell it which row you are trying to access. `results` doesn't have the property `password`, but the first row within it does.

I'm assuming you also have (or will include) logic that ensures there is at least one row? Otherwise, if that result does not (perhaps the user doesn't exist) then calling `results[0]` will also cause an error.

Comment: That is not the case in PHP correct? I can grab a row with mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and then get the password with $password = $row['password'].

Comment: It's the same concept, but if you're doing the usual `for($row = mysqli...)` then you're already referencing a specific row.